Template Parts with ACF fileds not showing on page WordPress Preview
I am wondering how can I make my fields content to show on the Gutenberg page preview when its coming from a template part.
Everything works fine on the frontend and the structure of the part is present when I inspect the preview (as well the space it takes, so that means the css present of the template part, but not the content coming from the ACF Fields.
I improvised this to force the templates to show, but still can't see the content:

/*
 * Template Name: Front Page
 */

get_header();

// TEMPLATE PARTS
if (is_preview()) {
    get_template_part('templates/parts/hero-front-page');
} else {
    get_template_part('templates/parts/hero-front-page');
    get_template_part('templates/parts/contact_button');
}


// CONTENT
the_content();

get_footer();


Here is the template part:

<div id="hero" class="h-3/5-screen md:h-screen">
    <?php
    $hero_background_image = get_field('hero_background-image');
    $hero_heading_h1 = get_field('hero_heading-h1');
    ?>

    <?php if ($hero_background_image) : ?>
        <div class="blue-to-green-gradient w-full h-full relative">
            <img class="object-cover object-center w-full h-full absolute top-0 left-0 -z-20 grayscale" src="<?php echo esc_url($hero_background_image['url']); ?>" alt="<?php echo esc_attr($hero_background_image['alt']); ?>" />

            <div class="w-full h-full px-6 pb-16 md:px-12 md:pb-24 lg:pb-40 xl:px-36 max-w-screen-2xl mx-auto">
                <?php if ($hero_heading_h1) : ?>
                    <h1 class="text-white text-4xl md:text-7xl xl:text-8xl font-semibold flex items-end h-full hyphens-auto md:hyphens-none"><?php echo esc_html($hero_heading_h1); ?></h1>
                <?php endif; ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    <?php endif; ?>

    <div id="scroll-down" class="hidden md:block absolute md:right-12 lg:left-1/2 lg:-translate-x-1/2 bottom-8 h-10 w-10 z-50"><img src="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/assets/arrow-scroll.svg'; ?>" alt="contact" class="object-contain object-center w-10 h-auto" /></div>
</div>


Any cue of what can be happening and how to solve it?
Thanks in advance

Possibly part of this known issue with meta info when previewing Gutenberg

I see... it seems the bug is there since 5 years now. Thanks a lot for your answer.
